# jQuery append and prepend dilema

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append a `<p>` tag to a `div` element. The problem is that I need to hide the div element but not the appended `<p>` tag. Somehow prepend it before or after. What can I do?

```
<div id='vid1'></div>


$('#vid1').append('<p class="ytclick">text</p>');
$('#vid1').hide();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DQ7VG/)

Comment: Fundamentally, you can't reasonably do that. Why would you want to? Perhaps if we knew the broader scope, we could help you fix the actual issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a visible element in a hidden one.

You should probably use `before` or `after` :

```
$('#vid1').after('<p class="ytclick">text</p>');
```